# For loop within a foreach loop java

Tags: java, database, postgresql, for-loop

So i have this code segment. searchStudentWith2RUCode() returns an Arraylist of Student objects. Student objects have various attributes such as forename, lastname, cprnumber, gpa etc.

```
 public void assignStudents() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
     ArrayList<Student> notYetAssignedStudents = searchStudentsWith2RUCode();
     ArrayList<Student> assignedStudents = new ArrayList<>()
          for (Education edu : eduList) {

               for (int i = 0; i < edu.getAmountOfFreeSpacesInEdu(); i++) {
                  assignedStudents.add(notAssignedStudents.get(i));                      
                  setAssignedStudentsAdmitted(assignedStudents.get(i).getCPR, assignedStudents.get(i).getPrio, assignedStudents.get(i).eduNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

setAssignedStudentsAdmitted updates my database and should set the field "sagsbehandling" in my table "students" as "Optaget" at each admitted student. However this doesnt work. 
Im suspecting my for loops, but Im lost, i can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Here is my setAssignedStudentsAdmitted method:

```
 public void setAssignedStudentsAdmitted(String CPR, int prio, int eduNumber) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    //Declare a UPDATE statement
    String updateStmt
            = "UPDATE Students SET sagsbehandling='Optaget' WHERE cprnr ='" + CPR + "' AND prio='" + prio + "' AND eduNumber='" + eduNumber + "';";

    //Execute UPDATE operation
    try {
        DatabaseController.dbExecuteUpdate(updateStmt);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print("Error occurred while DELETE Operation: " + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

}

And here is my dbExecuteUpdate method that is called in setAssignedStudentsAdmitted

```
    public static void dbExecuteUpdate(String sqlStmt) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //Declare statement as null
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        //Connect to DB (Establish Postgres Connection)
        databaseConnect();
        //Create Statement
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //Run executeUpdate operation with given sql statement
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStmt);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem occurred at executeUpdate operation : " + e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            //Close statement
            stmt.close();
        }
        //Close connection
        databaseDisconnect();
    }
}
```

It builds succesfully, but changes nothing in my Database.

Comment: Your first piece of code won't compile. You're at least missing a semi-colon, and it would be easier to read the code if you'd indent it properly too. Next, you should isolate which part of the code is actually problematic. Does `dbExecuteUpdate` work on its own? Next, stop building SQL like that - use parameterized SQL instead. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (amongst other problems).

Comment: Where your commit?

Comment: I might have lost some indentation and semi-colons copying my code here. Everything compiles in netbeans. dbExecuteUpdate works. Im imagining working in two for loops like that is my problem. I will work on parameterizing sql instead.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have autoCommit set to false? Make sure on your databaseConnect(), or for a quick test perform a Commit at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare a UPDATE statement
    String updateStmt
            = "UPDATE Students SET sagsbehandling='Optaget' WHERE cprnr ='" + CPR + "' AND prio='" + prio + "' AND eduNumber='" + eduNumber + "';";
```

The scope `updateStmt` is within `setAssignedStudentsAdmitted` method. So, how are you passing it in below method call ?

```
 public static void dbExecuteUpdate(String sqlStmt) 
         throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
```

Comment: That really doesn't seems to be good practice to call db when adding to List

Comment: I will instead do it outside of the for loop